# How can I inspect the code of a perl module installed?

Tags: perl, module

If I know that a certain `perl` module is installed on a system, eg. `MyCompany::Database::Utils`, how can I inspect the `perl` code of this module?

Answer (score 7):

Find the source code file with whatever means your OS provides.

If you're looking for a properly installed module, you can use `perldoc -l` to find the file or `perldoc -m` to print the file (thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, @mob):

```
perldoc -l List::Util
perldoc -m List::Util
```

If your module is `MyCompany::Database::Utils`, you know it must be in a path `MyCompany/Database/Utils.pm` below one of the paths in `@INC`.

You can list the default `@INC` paths with

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper(\@INC);'
```

If you are on a system with `mlocate` (such as most Linux/BSD distros), you can also find the file with

```
locate MyCompany/Database/Utils.pm
```

If you want to look into a distribution to see the full source (e.g. to find XS code, README, unit tests etc.), you can use [cpanminus'](https://cpanmin.us/) `--look` flag:

```
cpanm --look DateTime
```

Comment: `perldoc -l Foo::Bar` is a common trick, although it doesn't always work.

Comment: Also might be worth adding that you have to look at the distribution source to see XS code.

Comment: If `perldoc -l Foo::Bar` works, then `perldoc -m Foo::Bar` works too.

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, @mob I added `perldoc -[lm]` to the answer.

Comment: @mob What does `perldoc -m` do?

Comment: `perldoc -m` prints out the content of the module, the perl code and POD.

Answer (score 3):

Perl can find the module, so let Perl tell you where it found it!

```
perl -e'
   my $p = $ARGV[0];
   $p =~ s{::}{/}g;
   $p .= ".pm";
   require $p;
   print "$INC{$p}\n";
' MyCompany::Database::Utils
```

If the module contains POD, you can use the following shortcut:

```
perldoc -l MyCompany::Database::Utils
```

If that doesn't find the module, it could be that the script that uses MyCompany::Database::Utils manipulates `@INC` to allow it to find the module. If so, add the following to your script:

```
END {
   my $p = "MyCompany::Database::Utils";
   $p =~ s{::}{/}g;
   $p .= ".pm";
   print "$INC{$p}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in hash `%INC` documented in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) relates each module's .pm source file to its file system location

If you have

```
use MyCompany::Database::Utils;
```

then perl will search for a file like `MyCompany/Database/Utils.pm` relative to any of the directories listed in array `@INC` and, if it is found, will put its absolute location into the `%INC` hash

To find where each module has been located, you can simply dump the entire hash using [`Data::Dump`](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) or [`Data::Dumper`](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper). But if you're really only interested in one module then you can examine the relevant hash element. A statement like this

```
print "$INC{'MyCompany/Database/Utils.pm'}\n";
```

will show the absolute path where that .pm file was found and loaded