# List available functions in perl module

Tags: perl

First of all, I am entirely new in perl so I apologize if this is a rather basic question.

We have a perl script that calls on a module — lets name it module_x

It’s called in the script using this line.

> `require module_x`

Sadly, this does not have a documentation and we can’t access the server where this script is.

Is there a way to know what functions are available in the module? Similar to desc in python.

Comment: If you don't have a copy of the module and don't have access to the server that does, or the script that uses it, how do you expect to do anything with it?

Comment: If the module is accessible by the script you should be able to get the module, at least from inside the script - otherwise the script would not be able to use it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35471700/3081018) on finding out where the module is installed and from there you should be able to open the module and inspect the source code.

Comment: @Shawn sorry If my statement is not clear. We can run the module from a web application but we don’t have direct access to  the server where the module is. Hence we can’t open the source code.